# Shared http library

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I'm working on a project that uses Node.js and AngularJS. AngularJS has the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). This service is great for making web service calls to rest-based services. I'm curious, does anyone know of a Node module that will allow me to make web service calls, yet will let me use that code in the browser world as well? In a sense a HTTP service that I can use on the server and on the client?

I saw a package called `present` that allows you to get timestamps. This package has a fallback process so you can use it on both the client and the server. I'd love to be able to find something similar for http web service calls.

Comment: Hmm, good question, but I think it's two fundamentally different things. On the backend you would have to use the http module you mentioned while on the frontend it would have to wrap XMLHttpRequest (with the associated CORS issues). I can imagine you could build a library that does that, but is it worth the bother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use [browserify](http://browserify.org/). Browserify has a [version of the core http module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-browserify) for use in the browser that is automatically used when you `require('http');` in a script that you run through browserify.